# WMIC product where "name like..." - "no instances available" if run in batch file

Tags: wmic

I want to find what version of Outlook is running on specific workstations. If I manually run

```
wmic /node:"hostname" product where "Name like '%Office Outlook%'" get Name
```

in a command line, it works. But if I run it from a batch file, it returns "No instance(s) available".  I've even stripped everything else out of the batch file, so only this line is left - and I still get the same result. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a batch script file, escape your `%`s by prefacing each with another `%` as follows:

```
wmic /node:"hostname" product where "Name like '%%Office Outlook%%'" get Name
```

**For proof**, try next in your batch file:

```
echo ON
wmic /node:"hostname" product where "Name like '%%Office Outlook%%'" get Name
pause
```

You should see next `ECHO`ed command, the same as it would be typed from command prompt:

```
wmic /node:"hostname" product where "Name like '%Office Outlook%'" get Name
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::: some wmic output here :::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**For explanation**, read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> Escaping Percents
>
> The % character has a special meaning for command line parameters and
> FOR parameters.  
> To treat a percent **in a batch script file** as a
> regular character, double it: `%%`

Read [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/3439404) (entire thread) as well.